# SonarQube "Unexpected end of stream"

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

This problem has been going on for a while. It used to intermittent earlier but now it is consistently failing. The scan fails because of this.

org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.1.1:sonar plugin fails with error

```
[DEBUG] GET 200 http://sonarqubehost/deploy/plugins/findbugs/sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.4.3.jar | time=137ms

        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.1.1:sonar (default-cli) on project cm-ui-frontend: Fail to download sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.4.3.jar to /root/.sonar/cache/_tmp/fileCache7348481126430635122.tmp: unexpected end of stream -> [Help 1]
        org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.1.1:sonar (default-cli) on project cm-ui-frontend: Fail to download sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.4.3.jar to /root/.sonar/cache/_tmp/fileCache7348481126430635122.tmp
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
        Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fail to download sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.4.3.jar to /root/.sonar/cache/_tmp/fileCache7348481126430635122.tmp
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:36)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:81)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:117)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
            ... 20 more
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to download sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.4.3.jar to /root/.sonar/cache/_tmp/fileCache7348481126430635122.tmp
            at org.sonar.home.cache.FileCache.download(FileCache.java:98)
            at org.sonar.home.cache.FileCache.get(FileCache.java:82)
            at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchPluginInstaller.download(BatchPluginInstaller.java:103)
            at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchPluginInstaller.loadPlugins(BatchPluginInstaller.java:80)
            at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchPluginInstaller.installRemotes(BatchPluginInstaller.java:70)
            at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchPluginRepository.start(BatchPluginRepository.java:53)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
            at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
            at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$1.start(ComponentContainer.java:320)
            at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
            at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
            at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
            at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
            at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1016)
            at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009)
            at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767)
            at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:141)
            at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.start(Batch.java:103)
            at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.start(Batch.java:92)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.start(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:52)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.start(Unknown Source)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart(EmbeddedScanner.java:223)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start(EmbeddedScanner.java:159)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:60)
            ... 23 more
        Caused by: java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$ChunkedSource.read(HttpConnection.java:467)
            at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:50)
            at okio.RealBufferedSource.exhausted(RealBufferedSource.java:60)
            at okio.InflaterSource.refill(InflaterSource.java:101)
            at okio.InflaterSource.read(InflaterSource.java:62)
            at okio.GzipSource.read(GzipSource.java:80)
            at okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:371)
            at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
            at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1792)
            at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1769)
            at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1744)
            at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(FileUtils.java:1512)
            at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchPluginInstaller$FileDownloader.download(BatchPluginInstaller.java:160)
            at org.sonar.home.cache.FileCache.download(FileCache.java:96)
            ... 55 more
```

**Additional information**

sonarqube server version : 5.6

sonar maven plugin : 3.1.1

It is running on a Gitlab CI runner (docker in a docker)

Some times I get similar error for other jars like

```
Fail to download sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.jar
```

This seems to work fine though

```
curl -v -o a.jar http://sonarqubehost/deploy/plugins/findbugs/sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.4.3.jar
```

Any idea on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to download sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.4.3.jar to /root/.sonar/cache/_tmp/fileCache7348481126430635122.tmp

During analysis, plugins are pulled from the SonarQube server to the analysis machine. Your analysis machine is having an increasingly hard time doing that pull. Check the network between the two machines.

Comment: Thanks. The network seems to be fine (we are able to pull few other jars). This is the http req/resp for one of the components which failed download using tcpdump [gist](https://gist.github.com/muhilan/eb56f19e6b8d2cc78f50049f3bc22c9f)

Comment: Anything of interest in your server log?

Comment: I am working with the admin here. I will get it shortly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same problem and I just ran sonar maven command multiple times and issue got resolved.